# Delete personal information from PPT documnet using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to automate the process of deleting the "Author" and "Last Modified By" name stamp on a PowerPoint document. If you open MSFT Office document and click "File" then "Info", on the right hand side it shows "Related People" and gives you the name of the Author and whoever modified the document last.

To delete it manually, you would have to go back to file -> info -> check for issues -> inspect document -> make sure all boxes are checked -> click inspect document -> it should come up with a pop-up menu and highlight "Document properties and personal information" -> click remove all.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: Record a macro and then attempt to generalize the code if you need to.

Comment: There is no record macro option in my developer tab

Comment: The last release of Office that included a PPT macro recorder was Office 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff746376.aspx

This shows how to get a list of all document properties, and an example on how to change one of them.